# Private functions are usable on the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've discovered that private functions are still available from the worksheet. They're hidden, but if the user types their name, they will be called. Why? Is it supposed to work this way? Is there a way to completely block user defined functions from being used outside of the VBA project? I've tried declaring functions with the `Private` keyword, or placing `Option Private Module` at the top of my module. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Option Private Module, simply hides the UDF from the Function Wizard. This option lets you hide modules from external users and makes it easier to see your exposed function calls. You can still use them from the worksheet if you know the function's name. That's how it works.

However if you try to use that Private Function from anywhere else, for example Worksheet_Change event, you will not be able to. And if they are declared as "Public" with "Option Private Module" then they can be accessed.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266185%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> > > When a module contains Option Private Module, the public parts, for example, variables, objects, and user-defined types declared at module level, are still available within the project containing the module, but they are not available to other applications or projects.

Regarding your question

> > > Is there a way to completely block user defined functions from being used outside of the VBA project?

There are 2 ways that I can think of

1) Protecting your VBA Project so that the user doesn't know the name of the function.

2) Creating an Add-In

Comment: I should have noted that I'm working on an Add-In, and functions defined in the Add-In's private modules are usable in any open workbook.

Comment: I am curious as to how the user then know the function names? Is the code not protected?

Comment: I don't want to protect the code. Even if the code was protected, the user could guess a function's name or type it by chance. I'd rather not use cryptic names for my functions either because it would make the code less readable.

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't be of much help anymore as AFAIK there is no way around it :)

Comment: If you are ready to protect the code then one thing you can do is insert few numbers between your function names so that it will be difficult to guess them. For example Private Function GetPa55w0rd()

Comment: `+1` for the nice explanation.